# Setting Dr. Edit error

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api-client

I am following [all the steps from the readme file](https://github.com/googledrive/dredit/tree/master/java#setup-instructions) of DR. Edit for Java.

I have created a project in Eclipse, I copied java folder to my project and then, I add Drive and OAuth APIs.

I can't compile because there is an error with dependence:

```
import com.google.api.services.oauth2.model.Userinfo;
```

This error:

```
The import com.google.api.services.oauth2.model.Userinfo cannot be resolved
```

Im using google-api-client-1.16.0-rc and google-api-services-oauth2-v2-rev68-1.16.0-rc libraries (they were downloaded from Google Plugin for Eclipse as tutorial says).

What can I do?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of OAuth API doesn't contain the "Userinfo" class, it has been replaced by "Userinfoplus"

Ref: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/oauth2/v2/java/latest/com/google/api/services/oauth2/model/Userinfoplus.html

So just replace "Userinfo" with "Userinfoplus" and it should work.

`import com.google.api.services.oauth2.model.Userinfo;`